# Delegate from UITableViewCell doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, delegates

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which contains a button. When the button is clicked some action (delete the cell in this case) should perform in the `ViewController` where the `UITableView` is in.

I tried this using `delegate`.

In my custom cell I have

```
protocol CellDeleterDelegate: class {

    func deleteIngredAt(index:IndexPath)
    func deleteReceiptAt(index:Int)
    func reloadData()

}
```

and

`weak var delegate: CellDeleterDelegate?`

and

```
else {
            print("before Delete")
            delegate?.deleteIngredAt(index: indexP)
            print("after Delete")
            delegate?.reloadData()
            print(indexP)
        }
```

to call the needed functions (before the else I remove the data from the array which is the datasource for the table)

In my `ViewController` I have the following code:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CellDeleterDelegate{

[...]

func deleteIngredAt(index: IndexPath) {
        print("reached DeleteIngred")

        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [index], with: .automatic)

    }

    func deleteReceiptAt(index:Int) {

        print("reached DeleteIngred")

        let indices: IndexSet = [index]
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
        tableView.deleteSections(indices, with:  UITableView.RowAnimation.fade)

    }

    func reloadData() {
        print("reload reached")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

But none of the functions in my `ViewController` are called and I don't know why.
I used this earlier in another project and it worked fine.

Comment: write the following in cellForRowAt
cell.delegate = self

Comment: What's the point of `func reloadData()` when all you want to do is a print statement and reload the _tableView_

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed yes, that was it thank you

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi just to reload the data, in my previous project the table was reloaded before the animation from deleting the cell was finished, this was my workaround but not necessary in this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you forget to call cell.delegate = self     in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot that

Thank you